# Git LFS tracked file keeps producing a diff even when not changed

Tags: git, git-lfs, gitattributes

I have a file that keeps showing a diff that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. The file should be tracked in Git LFS. Can anyone make sense of why there is such a large diff even though the file hasn't been changed?

In my `.gitattributes` I have the following:

```
[attr]lfs -text filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs

...

**/Fonts/**/*.asset lfs
```

[image: Diff]

Comment: The thing shown on the left is an internal LFS pointer file; the thing shown on the right is some file's content (presumably after LFS was done fussing with the pointer file). The fact that there's a `diff=lfs` means that lfs should have been able to expand the pointer file so I don't know why it didn't, but I don't actually *use* git-LFS.

Comment: @torek Yeah, thats what I'm confused about. I'm wondering if it -wants- to be tracked by LFS, but its not? I'm very confused